# How to check Database health and connection pool health

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc, spring-boot-actuator

```
@Component
public class CustomHealthIndicator extends AbstractHealthIndicator {

@Override
protected void doHealthCheck(Health.Builder builder) throws Exception {
    // Use the builder to build the health status details that should be reported.
    // If you throw an exception, the status will be DOWN with the exception message.

    builder.up()
            .withDetail("app", "Alive and Kicking")
            .withDetail("error", "Nothing! I'm good.");
}
```

}
Here I noticed default health check happen through /health, I want to override something like above when dataConnection pool is short of available connection I need to return pod not ready. also i need to check health of the database. how to implement that?

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar for ages. 
Based in my experience with HikariDataSource that was my result:

```
@Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected void doHealthCheck(Health.Builder builder) throws Exception {

        HikariDataSource ds = (HikariDataSource) dataSource;
        Integer maxSize = ds.getMaximumPoolSize();
        Integer active = new HikariDataSourcePoolMetadata(ds).getActive();
        Double usage = new Double((active / maxSize) * 100);

        Health.Builder workingBuilder;

        if(usage > 90) {
            workingBuilder = builder.down();
        }else {
            workingBuilder = builder.up();
        }

        workingBuilder.withDetail("max", maxSize) //
        .withDetail("active", active)//
        .withDetail("usage", usage);
    }
```

Maybe there is a better approach by Actuator Metrics or with

```
   ds.getHealthCheckProperties()
   ds.getHealthCheckRegistry()
```

Comment: hi Thanks bemar, does it work in openshift am connecting with UDB